# What is the center of this ring?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $\mathbb{C}$ be the field of complex numbers and $F$ the field of rational functions in $x$ over $\mathbb{C}$.

Consider the set of Laurent series $D$, of all $\sum_{m=-k}^{\infty} f_iy^i$ in $y$ over $F$, where $yr(x)y^{−1}=r(2x)$, for any $r(x) \in F$.

Then $D$ is a division ring with center $\mathbb{C}$.

I couldn't see that $Z(D)=\mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  In particular a central element needs to commute with $y$.  For this to happen, you’d need $r(x)=r(2x)$.  When does that happen?

Update:

You mentioned in your solution-comment that you decided that meant a central element is then apparently a Laurent polynomial over $\mathbb C$ in indeterminate $y$. But then the next obvious followup is to do look at $x^{-1}rx=r$ where $r$ is a central element in the form of a Laurent series over $\mathbb C$ in indeterminate $y$.

Answer (score 1):

if $r(x)=r(2x)$, of course $r(x)$ is a constant polynomial. So $r(x) \in \mathbb{C}$

But in this case, we have elements of $Z(D)$ is in the form $\sum_{m=-k}^{\infty} a_my^m$ where $a_m \in \mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Are you trying to respond with a comment using this answer? Because it seems like you are using my hint but not getting to the end.